# Proposition 5.21 in Atiyah-MacDonald

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

There's just one step in this proof I can't see for the life of me.

Set up: We have a field K and an algebraically closed field $\Omega$.  $(B, g)$ is maximal in the set $\Sigma$ of ordered pairs $(A, f)$ where $A$ is a subring of K and $f$ a homomorphism into $\Omega$, where $\Sigma$ has the partial order $(A, f) \leq (A', f')$ if $A$ is a subring of $A'$ and $f'|_{A} = f$.  The overall claim is that $(B, g)$ is a valuation of $K$.  We let $M$ be the unique maximal ideal of $B$ (which exists).  We take $x \in K$ with $x \neq 0$ and may assume that $M[x]$ is not the unit ideal of $B' = B[x]$(by a lemma) and so is contained in some maximal ideal $M'$.  Let $k = B/M$ and $k' = B'/M'$.

The claim I don't understand: Since $k' = k[\bar{x}]$ for $\bar{x}$ the image of x in k' (which I see), $\bar{x}$ is algebraic over k.

Comment: Nevermind, $\bar{x}$ transcendental would give us an indeterminate in $k'$, which is a field since $M'$ isn't just $M[x]$ but is a maximal ideal containing it.  Sorry.

Answer (score 13):

If your doubt is what I think it is, then remember: if $\,k/F\,$ is a fields extension and $\,w\in k\,$, then $\,F(w)=F[w]\Longleftrightarrow w\,$ is algebraic over $\,F\,$.

In you case, since $\,k\,$ is a field, it then equals the polynomial ring in $\,k[\overline x]\,$ iff this element is algebraic over $\,k\,$

Comment: Yes, it is what you think:+1

Answer (score 6):

Suppose $\bar x$ is not algebraic over $k$.
Then $k[\bar x]$ is isomorphic to the polynomial ring $k[X]$.
However $k[X]$ is not a field(any polynomial of degree $\geq 1$ in $k[X]$ is not invertible in $k[X]$).
Hence $k[\bar x]$ is not a field.
This is a contradiction.
Hence $\bar x$ is algebraic over $k$.